# how to get a list of all entities in EF 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am building an MVC 4 app.  I have view that has a dropdown that needs to display all the tables (entities) used..

How can I do that?  I am using EF 5 code first with configurations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892926/entity-framework-get-list-of-tables

Comment: Belogix - I saw this previously, but none of what the answer says works...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all model types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928716/get-all-model-types)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code will get them for you, of course the ones that has been imported to your EDM which necessarily is not all the tables in your data store.

```
var tableNames = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace)
                        .Select(t => t.Name)
                        .ToList();
```

For code first:

```
using System.Data.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

...

using (dbcontext context = new TestContext())
{
   ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
   MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;
   IEnumerable<EntityType> tables = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.SSpace);

}
```

Comment: there is no such thing as MetadataWorkspace in my context

Comment: Radenko - Can I ask you one more question, I have added a custom attribute to some entities called DoNotAudit.  How do I only get a list of tables that don't have an attribute?

Answer (score 2):

This work very well for me on EF 6

```
        public List<string> EntityNames()
        {
            ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContext).ObjectContext;
            MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;
            IEnumerable<EntityType> tables = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.SSpace);

            List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            foreach (var table in tables)
            {
                var entityName = table.FullName.Replace("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.", "");
                lst.Add($"{entityName}");
            }

            return lst;
        }
```