# How to get a strongly typed list of all entities in your model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using a code first with EF6, and I've seen the answer here:

- [how to get a list of all entities in EF 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182716/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-entities-in-ef-5)
- [Get all model types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928716/get-all-model-types)
- [Entity Framework - Get List of Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892926/entity-framework-get-list-of-tables)

And they all work, they get the list of entities and you can use them.

However, I'm after something slightly different. There are cases when I end up using a specific `EntityEnum` to maintain a separate list of all my entities, so that I can reference them with a strong type.

Is there a means, something like T4MVC, by which I can get a strongly typed list of all my entities, so I can call `MeProject.Models.Customers.Name` or something similar?

Comment: When you "reference them with a strong type", are you truly dealing with just an enum where the value is an integer, or do you mean getting a reference to the actual Entity type such as `typeof(ProductEntity)`?  You asked for a list of entities, but `MeProject.Models.Customers.Name` looks like you are accessing a property of an entity.  Could probably use some elaboration or you're probably not going to get answers that meet what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Hang on a second there @AaronLS! I think you've just pointed me in the right direction with `typeof(EntityClass)` as you can get a string... It's pretty much there, with a small wrapper it may just work?

Comment: @RemarkLime Yes you can, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/179711/84206