# EF CodeFirst - Get all entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've the next context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
   public virtual DbSet<Provider> Providers { get; set; }
   public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Exists any method to get all entities of my context? 
Something like `MyContext.GetAllEntities()` that returns `{Customer, Provider, Product}`.

**EDIT**
I want retrieve the entities in `OnModelCreating` for creating indexes in determinated properties that are decorated with custom attribute.
On `OnModelCreating` I can not access to the context how it's explains in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182716/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-entities-in-ef-5)

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get a list of all entities in EF 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182716/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-entities-in-ef-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code you can call ToList() on all your DbSets. Otherwise you would have to write a stored procedure that does a `UNION` and just call the sp.

```
public List<object> GetAllEntities(MyContext db)
{
    var results = new List<object>();
    results.AddRange(db.Customers.ToList());
    results.AddRange(db.Providers.ToList());
    results.AddRange(db.Products.ToList());

    return results;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Fine for nameless list, use reflection then.

```
MyContext db = new MyContext();
var resultsList = new List<object>();

PropertyInfo[] info = db.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach(PropertyInfo item in info)
{
   //Check for array, that it is a DbSet etc...
   var setType = item.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments[0];

   resultsList.AddRange(db.Set(setType).ToListAsync().Result);
}

return resultsList;
```

Comment: The OP didn't mean to get data by the entity names.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response from [Wurd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3586144/wurd):

```
private IEnumerable<Type> GetAllEntities ()
{
   var entities = new List<Type> ();
   PropertyInfo[] info = GetType ().GetProperties (BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
   foreach (PropertyInfo item in info) {
      var setType = item.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo ().GenericTypeArguments[0];
      entities.Add (setType);
   }
   return entities;
}
```