# Entity Framework Core: Get a List of All the Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I get a list of all the tables in Entity Framework Core in a db context?

The following answer is for previous version in Entity Framework 5, we are currently using EF Core 3.

[how to get a list of all entities in EF 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182716/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-entities-in-ef-5)

[Entity Framework - Get List of Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892926/entity-framework-get-list-of-tables)

```
var tableNames = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace)
                        .Select(t => t.Name)
                        .ToList();
```

We just want to display all the database in a report with EF Core. Raw Sql is `select * from sys.tables or information_schema.tables`, however looking for EFCore way

Comment: There are no such methods in Core. You could however use a raw query. Though if you explain the use case there might be other approaches

Comment: we just want to display all the database in a report with EF Core,  I believe raw sql is select * from sys.tables, or informatioin_schema.tables,  however looking for EFCore way,  cc @TheGeneral

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The list of all tables in the database - no. The list of all entities mapped to a context and information about their database mappings (tables, columns, indexes etc.) - sure. You would use the EF Core metadata API which is much more intuitive than EF ones. Start with `Model` property of the `DbContext` and explore the available (extension) methods.

For instance:

```
var tableNames = context.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Select(t => t.GetTableName())
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: hi maybe you can help out with this question? thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031605/entity-framework-get-the-datatype-of-metadata-iproperty

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the internals of EFCore scaffolding to retrieve all the tables

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v5.0.7/src/EFCore.Design/Scaffolding/Internal/ReverseEngineerScaffolder.cs

such as the below:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
                    .AddLogging()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkDesignTimeServices()
                    .AddSingleton<LoggingDefinitions, SqliteLoggingDefinitions>()                                              
                    .AddSingleton<IDatabaseModelFactory, SqliteDatabaseModelFactory>()                                   
                    .BuildServiceProvider();
    
                var model = serviceCollection.GetRequiredService<IDatabaseModelFactory>();
                var dbOptions = new DatabaseModelFactoryOptions();
                var databaseModelFactory = model.Create(**Put connectionstring here**, dbOptions);

var tables = databaseModelFactory.Tables; //Contains all the tables.
```

This currently works with EFCore 5.07 and sqllite not tested this with other providers yet. As always, when tapping into internals be warned that upgrading EFCore could break this.