# How to get list of database tables in C# code (in vendor independent way)?

Tags: c#, sql

What are database vendor independent ways to obtain list of tables in C# code?

I heard about three:

1. ADO .NET, `IDbConnection.GetSchema("Tables")`
2. Linq, `new System.Data.Linq.DataContext(IDbConnection).Mapping.GetTables();` (>=3.5, System.Data.Linq.dll).
3. EF, [Entity Framework - Get List of Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892926/entity-framework-get-list-of-tables)

But this mean that somewhere there are a set of adapters for syntax of each vendor.

Is there a standard SQL syntax for this operation?

What are other ways to get list of tables in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [ANSI standard Information Schema Views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

Supported by: SQL Server, Postgresql, MySQL, ...

Not implemented by Oracle, DB2, SQLite,...

Comment: which standart defines this syntax? I think it is not vendor independent (it's microsoft-related)

Comment: No it isn't not only SQL Server. It is ANSI standard implemented by Postgreql, MySQL, SQL Server, ...

Comment: @user1709408 . . . It is standard and will work on SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL, and probably some other databases.  It don't think it  works on Oracle, MS Access, or DB2.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a link to the text of standart? i think, that it's name is "SQL:2003 core feature F021 Basic information schema (ANSI/ISO SQL:2003 standard Part 11 Schemata)"

Comment: http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=53685

Comment: @user1709408 As I thought original is not free. And your second link is draft version `THIS DOCUMENT IS STILL UNDER STUDY AND SUBJECT TO CHANGE. IT SHOULD NOT
BE USED FOR REFERENCE PURPOSES.`

Comment: @user1709408: it's a **standard** (with a **d** at the end) - not a "standart" ....

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25423/why-do-non-native-english-users-often-spell-standard-as-standart

Comment: @marc Probably comment above from `user1709408`  is for you.

Comment: SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'; for Postgresql.