# EF code first: The EntitySet name 'TestDBContext1.Customers' could not be found

Tags: entity-framework

I am getting this error

> Additional information: The EntitySet name 'TestDBContext1.Customers'
>   could not be found.

I am trying to call a SQL Server stored procedure which returns multiple result sets.

This is my full code:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new TestDBContext1())
    {
        db.Database.Initialize(force: false);

        // Create a SQL command to execute the stored procedure 
        var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[MultiResultSet]";

        try
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Open();

            // Run the stored procedure 
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // Read Blogs from the first result set 
            var customers = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                        .ObjectContext
                        .Translate<Customer>(reader, "Customers", MergeOption.AppendOnly);

            foreach (var item in customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.FirstName);
            }

            // Move to second result set and read Posts 
            reader.NextResult();

            var Addresses = ((IObjectContextAdapter) db)
                        .ObjectContext
                        .Translate<Addresses>(reader, "Addresses", MergeOption.AppendOnly);

            foreach (var item in Addresses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Address1);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This line throws the above error:

```
var customers = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
.ObjectContext
.Translate<Customer>(reader, "Customers", MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

My database tables are `Customers` and `Addresses`. Why am I getting this error? What to change in my code?

The interesting things is when I code like the below way then all works fine.

```
var customers = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
.ObjectContext
.Translate<Customer>(reader);
```

The moment I remove `"Customers", MergeOption.AppendOnly` from code then code works fine. just do not understand what was wrong in my above code. please some one help me to understand this. Thanks

Comment: Do you have `public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }` in your `TestDBContext1` class?

Comment: yes public ` public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }`

Comment: Then the entity set name is "Customer" (w/o 's' at the end)

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks yes you are right. tell me if without entity set we can work then what is the benefit to use entity set name ? see this code which works without entity set name. `var customers = ((IObjectContextAdapter) db)
.ObjectContext
.Translate<Customer>(reader);`

Comment: only entity sets are able to be used in stored procedures, otherwise you can manually retrieve your dbset's of any mapped types.

Answer (score 3):

If your set doesn't have a name, you can just write

```
var customers = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<Customer>(reader);
```

The default for that `MergeOption` is already `AppendOnly`, so you don't have to worry about that parameter as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your entity set *has* a name. I think if you pass `null` as the second input to `Translate`, it will do what you want:

```
var customers = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
    .ObjectContext
    .Translate<Customer>(reader, null, MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

Comment: sorry i set null but no benefit and got a error msg `The argument 'entitySetName' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.`

Comment: is there any way to see entity set name from code ?

Comment: Ah, you're right, sorry. It's annoying because I can see that internally a null parameter would be handled fine if the null check were removed. You might take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3893502/76123). I think it may give you some ideas about how to see the entity set names.